# How to parallize across workers in Dataflow when reading from one huge file

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So essentially I've got a pipeline that reads pubsub for when a JSON file uploaded then reads each element and modifies the fields and then outputs each as a one row csv that can then be loaded and concated together for further data operations. The problem I'm facing is that the ParDo is not spawning more workers for this step and takes multiple days to complete on the one stage of modifiing each element os the JSON file. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

I've tried ensuring the file is split up before sending to parDo and that step complete fairly quickly but the parDo does everything on one worker and I can't seem to get it to spawn more. I've ensured it's allowed to have up to 4 workers.

Comment: You have to write a splittable DoFn (SDF). Check this [workshop video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQdtaaWxN0Y&list=PL4dEBWmGSIU9OkXQU2OAXmITPLhiMSPRp&index=56) from the Beam Summit 2022. The first 45 minutes is theory, and then they present a demo with a use case which is pretty close to what you need (before they go on to streaming).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with CaptainNabla. The easiest way to solve this would be to use a Splittable DoFn.

I could be wrong but I believe that if your large file is being read by a
DoFn, it’s likely that the file is being processed atomically inside that
DoFn, which cannot be parallelized further by the runner.

One purpose-built way around that constraint is by using [Splittable
DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns) which could be used to allow each split to read a portion of the
file.

More information here - https://beam.apache.org/blog/splittable-do-fn-is-available/